# Real forking UDP server asserts and core dumps

Tags: node.js, udp, fork, assert

This worked flawlessly in node 0.6.19 but now fails.

I wrote a forking UDP server in node. However, node doesn't have a real fork and cluster doesn't do UDP, so I wrote a module in C++ that simply calls fork (the module that contains this function is called "hasher")

```
static Handle<Value> spoon(const Arguments& args) // node sees this function as "fork"
{
HandleScope scope;
pid_t rval = fork();
if (rval < 0)
{
    return ThrowException(Exception::Error(String::New("Unable to fork daemon, pid < 0.")));
}
Handle<Value> n = v8::Number::New(rval);
return n;
}
```

I bind the UDP port, and fork all the children.

```
udp_server.bind(argv.udp_listen_port, '0.0.0.0');

// now create multiple children (loop starting with 1 is on purpose)                                                                
for (var i = 1; i < argv.multiple; i++)
{
    var pid = hasher.fork();           
    if (pid == 0)
        break;
}
```

Theoretically, the child processes should not know that someone else is sharing that port and should behave normally. However, I almost immediately (1 or 2 incoming UDP packets) trigger an assert message:

```
node-0.10.29: ../deps/uv/src/unix/stream.c:499: uv__server_io: Assertion `events == 1'

failed.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Anyone have a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: Well, fork is very dangerous if you do not control all code inside your process. Probably, the forked processes now share something that they do not expect to share. That's why forking is such a bad model. It is hard to ensure that this is a safe operation.